# Count Record Only On Unique Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, aggregate-functions

I have a table as follow:

```
  ID  |  Name  
------|--------
   1  |  Kevin
   1  |  Kevin
   2  |  Jim
   3  |  Jim
   4  |  Alex
```

I'm trying to get a count of `Name` with a unique `ID`. Expected results would be:

```
  ID  |  Name  |  Count
------|--------|---------
   1  |  Kevin |    1
   2  |  Jim   |    2
   3  |  Jim   |    2
   4  |  Alex  |    1
```

I had thought I would be able to do this with a query similar to

```
select distinct ID
  , Name
  , count(Name) over (partition by Name)
from table
```

but this query is giving a count of `2` for Kevin as well and the logic eludes me to keep `Kevin` at a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
select id, name, count(*) over(partition by name) cnt
from mytable
group by id, name
```